# Phoenix Channels - broadcasting from controller - how to find current_user?

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, phoenix-channels

I have an app where I broadcast some submissions for forms in the submission_controller, like this:

```
Formerer.Endpoint.broadcast("forms:#{form.id}", "new_submission", payload)
```

However, what I try to do now, is to make sure that only the current_user has access to the submissions broadcasted for its forms. (eg, current_user will have no way to see the submission for "forms:2" if form 2 belongs to another user).

I manage to do this in the channel `join` action by filtering the forms only for the user id which I assigned to the channel in the connect action:

```
user = Repo.get(Formerer.User, socket.assigns.user_id)
```

But for the `broadcast` I have no `socket` available.

#### My questions:

1. Is there a way to find somehow the socket by the channel topic?
   something like:

   ```
   %Phoenix.Socket{assigns: %{user_id: user_id}, topic: "forms:1"} = ALL_OPEN_SOCKETS?!
   ```

After that I could just see if `user_id == submission.user_id`, and broadcast if true

2. If that is not possible, what would be a best practice to do this, and to ensure only the current_user has access to their form submissions?

Comment: Why you don't verify your submission from the client since you have already used `Endpoint.broadcast/3`.Like you can submit your `user_id` along with your `payload` in your submission_controller and then you verify it when broadcast the `payload` to the `form_channel` is listening `new_submission` event.

Comment: That means that the submission info will still be broadcasted. My dilema is how to stop them to be broadcasted at all if not the correct user.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use the `intercept` api and create a `handle_out` function for the event. In the `handle_out` function you will have the socket. You can verify the user_id stored there. It its correct, `push socket, event, message`, otherwise do nothing except `{:ok, socket}`.

Edit

Here is a code example:

```
defmodule MyApp.Web.UserChannel do
  Use MyApp.Web, :channel

  intercept ["new_submission"]

  def handle_out("new_submission", msg, socket) do
    if msg[:user_id] == socket.assigns[:user_id] do
      push socket, "new_submission, msg
    end
    {:noreply, socket}
  end
end
```

Then you can just broadcast on the `new_submission` event anywhere and the socket will channel will take care of pushing the event out only three user defined in the payload.